# how to convert linear equation to cnf

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I'm working on reduction from binary puzzle problem into sat.
one of the game's rule is that in each row/column numbers of 1s equals to numbers of 0. I found a solution but it's exponential.
Therefore, I need to turn the equation: 
$X_1+ X_2+..... +X_{2n} =n$ , $X_i$ is $0$ or $1$, to cnf.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to say, $X_1+ X_2+\dots +X_{2n} =n$ where $X_i$ is $0$ or $1$ is to say, $\exists_{=n}(X_1+ X_2+\dots+X_{2n})$, meaning that exactly *n* of the literals are true.

The CNF for this can be split into two subproblems, "n or fewer of the literals are true" and "n or more of the literals are true".  When these two groups of constraints are put together, the intersection is "exactly *n* of the literals are true".

1) To state the constraint: "n or more of the literals are true", generate all [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of the literals taken $n+1$ at time.

For example, given the elements:

```
(x₁, x₂, x₃, x₄, x₅, x₆)
```

The CNF for "no fewer than 3 three are true" is generated by taking the literals four at a time:

```
(x₁, x₂, x₃, x₄)
(x₁, x₂, x₃, x₅)
(x₁, x₂, x₃, x₆)
(x₁, x₂, x₄, x₅)
(x₁, x₂, x₄, x₆)
(x₁, x₂, x₅, x₆)
(x₁, x₃, x₄, x₅)
(x₁, x₃, x₄, x₆)
(x₁, x₃, x₅, x₆)
(x₁, x₄, x₅, x₆)
(x₂, x₃, x₄, x₅)
(x₂, x₃, x₄, x₆)
(x₂, x₃, x₅, x₆)
(x₂, x₄, x₅, x₆)
(x₃, x₄, x₅, x₆)
```

2) To state the constraint: "n or fewer of the literals are true", generate all [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of the *negated* literals taken $n+1$ at time.

For example, given the elements:

```
(x₁, x₂, x₃, x₄, x₅, x₆)
```

The CNF for "no more than 3 three are true" is generated by taking the negated literals four at a time:

```
(~x₁, ~x₂, ~x₃, ~x₄)
(~x₁, ~x₂, ~x₃, ~x₅)
(~x₁, ~x₂, ~x₃, ~x₆)
(~x₁, ~x₂, ~x₄, ~x₅)
(~x₁, ~x₂, ~x₄, ~x₆)
(~x₁, ~x₂, ~x₅, ~x₆)
(~x₁, ~x₃, ~x₄, ~x₅)
(~x₁, ~x₃, ~x₄, ~x₆)
(~x₁, ~x₃, ~x₅, ~x₆)
(~x₁, ~x₄, ~x₅, ~x₆)
(~x₂, ~x₃, ~x₄, ~x₅)
(~x₂, ~x₃, ~x₄, ~x₆)
(~x₂, ~x₃, ~x₅, ~x₆)
(~x₂, ~x₄, ~x₅, ~x₆)
(~x₃, ~x₄, ~x₅, ~x₆)
```

Last, concatenate the two CNFs to generate all solutions to the linear formula where the only half of the literals are true :-)

Comment: What if there are coefficience for variables? How to convert $1x_1+2x_2+......+nx_n \geq n$ to CNF?